# Trying to add a Widget to a Widget List

Tags: flutter

I am pretty new to flutter and having some issues I cant figure out. I have created a component and am mapping over it in order to render data from each instance. However I am having trouble adding a Text Widget after/before my List. I have tried adding a `.add` to it but it threw an error because the List is not of the same type. I am pretty sure I am missing something pretty obvious but I can seem to figure it out. Below is the working code:

```
 List<Widget> trucks() {
// var trucks
// trucks = 
    return DUMMY_TRUCKS
        .map(
          (truck) => TruckComponent(truck.id, truck.name),
        )
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Team Name"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: trucks()
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

What I am trying to do is also include a Text Widget before my map to say Choose your truck but I am not quite sure how.